# Javascript as Jquery Function Call?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, jquery, javascript

Refer to
[Nice scroll to wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128213/nice-scroll-to-wordpress/128238?noredirect=1#128238)

wordpress runs jquery in noconflicts mode which means that you either need to write your JS code using the jQuery function call

```
var seq = 0;

  $(document).ready(function() {    
    $("html").niceScroll({styler:"fb",cursorcolor:"#000"});

    $("#mainlogo img").eq(1).hide();
    function goSeq() {
      var nxt = (seq+1)%2;
      $("#mainlogo img").eq(seq).fadeIn(2000);
      $("#mainlogo img").eq(nxt).fadeOut(2000);
      seq = nxt;
      setTimeout(goSeq,2500);
    };
    goSeq();

    $(window).load(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#gmbox div").animate({'top':60},1500,"easeOutElastic");
      },1500);
    });

    function trackLink(link, category, action) {
      try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'tracklink' ,'click',link.href ]);
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
      }catch(err){}
    }

    $('[rel="outbound"]').click(function(e){      
      try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound','click',this.href]);
      }catch(err){}
    });

  });
```

This is the javascript that i want to add in functions.js using the Jquery function call.

To make it work I inserted $ in (). Could you please correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Codex section on [jQuery noConflict wrappers in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers):

> [...]if you really like the short $ instead of jQuery, you can use the following wrapper around your code:
>
> ```
> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
>     // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
>     // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
> });
> ```

So, in your case, you could use

```
var seq = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("html").niceScroll({styler:"fb",cursorcolor:"#000"});

    $("#mainlogo img").eq(1).hide();
    function goSeq() {
      var nxt = (seq+1)%2;
      $("#mainlogo img").eq(seq).fadeIn(2000);
      $("#mainlogo img").eq(nxt).fadeOut(2000);
      seq = nxt;
      setTimeout(goSeq,2500);
    };
    goSeq();

    $(window).load(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#gmbox div").animate({'top':60},1500,"easeOutElastic");
      },1500);
    });

    function trackLink(link, category, action) {
      try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'tracklink' ,'click',link.href ]);
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
      }catch(err){}
    }

    $('[rel="outbound"]').click(function(e){      
      try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound','click',this.href]);
      }catch(err){}
    });

});
```

...assuming that all the rest of your JS code is correct, of course.